# AngularJS $http put raw HTML element in the body

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <p>Response from process.php is : {{message}}</p>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){
      $http({
        method : "post",
        url : "process.php"
      })
      .then(function(response){
        // First function handle success
        $scope.message = response.data;
      }, function(response){
        // Second function handle error
        $scope.message = response.status +' ('+ response.statusText + ' )';
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
    $data = "<h1>Hey, how are you...???</h1>";
    echo $data;
?>
```

> Response from process.html is : `<h1>Hey, how are you...???</h1>`

You can see that the output is not as expected. It puts the **h1** element in the body. But the output should be an **heading**.
How can I do this..?? Any suggestions please.

**SOLVED**

```
<div ng-bind-html="messageHtml"></div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $sce){
           $http({
                method : "post",
                url : "process.php"
              })
              .then(function(response){
                 // First function handle success
                 $scope.message = response.data;
                 $scope.messageHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message)
               }, function(response){
                  // Second function handle error
                  $scope.messageHtml = response.status +' ('+ response.statusText + ' )';
              })
          });
    </script>
```

Comment: Use `ng-bind-html` From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 2):

Found solution

I have to use `$sce` with `ng-bind-html` .

**HTML**

`<p ng-bind-html="messageHtml"></p>`

**Controller**

```
$scope.message = response.data;
$scope.messageHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-bind-html like this

```
<p ng-bind-html="message" ></p>
```

Comment: Tried, but No output

Answer (score 1):

Check This code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http,$sce){
      $http({
        method : "post",
        url : "process.php"
      })
      .then(function(response){
        // First function handle success
        $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
      }, function(response){
        // Second function handle error
        $scope.message = response.status +' ('+ response.statusText + ' )';
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Response from process.php is : <span ng-bind-html="message"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, I already answered this code above. Thanks bdw

Comment: More important is, your problem fixed, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-bind-html` directive.

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<p>Response from process.php is : </p><div ng-bind-html="message"></div>
```

Comment: Tried, but No output

Comment: What error, are you getting..$sanitize service must be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have created a directive for just this scenario. You need to have [`angular-sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) included in your project.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('yourModule')
        .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
            return function (text) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Then in your HTML, you can write:

```
<p>{{message | to_trusted}}</p>
```